# SQL finding average value of n rows where n is a sum of a field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data that looks like this.

SoldToRetailer

```
OrderDate  | Customer  | Product  | price | units
-------------------------------------------------
1-jun-2011 | customer1 | Product1 | $10   | 5
2-jun-2011 | customer1 | Product1 | $5    | 3
3-jun-2011 | customer1 | Product2 | $10   | 4
4-jun-2011 | customer1 | Product1 | $4    | 4
5-jun-2011 | customer2 | Product3 | $10   | 1
```

SalesByRetailers

```
Customer  | Product  | units
-----------------------------
customer1 | Product1 | 5
customer2 | Product3 | 1
```

Here's what I need.

Sales(average price)

```
Customer  | Product  | units | Average Price
--------------------------------------------
customer1 | Product1 | 5     | $3.44
customer2 | Product3 | 1     | $10
```

Average Price is defined as the average price of the most recent SoldToRetailer Prices that add up to the units.

So in the first case, I grab the orders from June 4th and June 2nd.  I don't need (actually want) the orders from june 1st to be included.

EDIT:  Hopefully a better explanation.

I'm attempting to determine the correct (most recent) price where an item was sold to a retailer. It's LIFO order for the prices. The price is determined by averaging the price sold over the last n orders.  Where n = total retail sales for a particular product and customer.

In SQL pseudcode it would look like this.

```
Select s1.Customer, s1.product, average(s2.price)
from SalesByRetailers s1
join SoldToRetailer s2
on s1.customer=s2.customer
and s1.product=s2.product
and ( select top (count of records where s2.units = s1.units) from s2 order by OrderDate desc)
```

What I need to return is the number of records from SoldToRetailer where the sum of units is >= SalesByRetailer Units.

It looks like it could be solved by a RANK or rowover partition, but I'm at a loss.

The SoldToRetailer table is ginormous so performance is at a premium.

Running on SQL 2008R2
Thanks for helping

Comment: Where does "product1 the total orders are 9" come from? unitsSold, unitsInventory? Whatis desired output? Why not data from 1-jun-2011 for product1? This isn't too clear...

Comment: Edited to improve clarity.  9 is sum of unitsSold and unitsInventory.  Desired output is customer, product, average price.  The detail records nee to be sorted on date, so only the most recent records are returned.

Comment: how do you get to average price 3.44 ? And why do you have units in both customer and orders ?

Comment: average price is ((4*4)+(5*3))/9.  Orders table is what we sent to the customer.  The customer table is what they actually sold.

Comment: *edit* Nevermind, I see you're intentionally leaving out June 1 orders

Comment: you are really not explaining the problem well. What is the customer table and why are you dividing by 9 ? It would make some sense to divide by 7. How many recent orders or days are used to determine the average price ?

Comment: Another edit.  It's not based on days.  It's based on orders.  If I have a record with 10 units sold, then I need to figure out the average price for the last 10 units.  Could be all days, or it could be just one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used 3 techniques.  First I created a table with an over by clause to give me a sorted list of products and prices, then I edited the table to add in the running average.  An OUTER APPLY sub select fixded my final problem.  Hopefully the code will help someone else with a similar problem.

A shout out to Jeff Moden of SQLSderverCentral.com fame for the running average help.

```
     SELECT d.ProductKey,
         d.ActualDollars,
         d.Units,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductKey ORDER BY d.OrderDateKey DESC) AS RowNumber,
         NULL                                                                  AS RunningTotal,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 4), 0)                                            AS RunningDollarsSum,
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 4), 0)                                            AS RunningAverage
  INTO   #CustomerOrdersDetails
  FROM   dbo.orders d
  WHERE  customerKey = @CustomerToSelect

  --DB EDIT...  Google "Quirky update SQL Server central.  Jeff Moden's version of a
  --Running total.  Holy crap it's faster.  tried trangular joins before. 
  CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Index1]
    ON #CustomerOrdersDetails ( ProductKey ASC, RowNumber ASC )

  DECLARE @RunningTotal INT
  DECLARE @PrevProductKey INT
  DECLARE @RunningDollarsSum DECIMAL(10, 4)

  UPDATE #CustomerOrdersDetails
  SET    @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = CASE
                                          WHEN ProductKey = @PrevProductKey THEN c.Units + ISNULL(@RunningTotal, 0)
                                          ELSE c.Units
                                        END,
         @RunningDollarsSum = RunningDollarsSum = CASE
                                                    WHEN ProductKey = @PrevProductKey THEN c.ActualDollars + ISNULL(@RunningDollarsSum, 0)
                                                    ELSE c.ActualDollars
                                                  END,
         @PrevProductKey = ProductKey,
         RunningAverage = @RunningDollarsSum / NULLIF(@RunningTotal, 0)
  FROM   #CustomerOrdersDetails c WITH (TABLOCKX)
  OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

  -- =============================================
  -- Update Cost fields with average price calculation
  -- =============================================
  UPDATE d
  SET    DolSoldCostUSD = COALESCE(d.DolSoldCostUSD,
                                   d.UnitsSold * a.RunningAverage),
  FROM   dbo.inbound d
         OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                      FROM   #CustomerOrdersDetails ap
                      WHERE  ap.ProductKey = d.ProductKey
                             AND d.UnitsSold + d.UnitsOnHand + d.UnitsOnOrder + d.UnitsReceived + d.UnitsReturned >= RunningTotal
                      ORDER  BY RunningTotal) AS a
```

Comment: Thanks for the shout, Dayton!  I truly appreciate it!  Nice job on your code, as well.

Comment: Just giving credit where credit is due Jeff.  I still hear RBAR in my head anytime I start to type CURSOR ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (customer varchar(15), product varchar(15), qty int, price decimal(6,2))

insert into @table (customer, product, qty, price)
values
('customer1', 'product1', 5, 3),
('customer1', 'product1', 4, 4),
('customer1', 'product1', 3, 2),
('customer1', 'product1', 2, 13),
('customer1', 'product1', 3, 3),

('customer1', 'product2', 5, 1),
('customer1', 'product2', 4, 7),
('customer1', 'product2', 2, 5),
('customer1', 'product2', 6, 23),
('customer1', 'product2', 2, 1),

('customer2', 'product1', 2, 1),
('customer2', 'product1', 4, 4),
('customer2', 'product1', 7, 3),
('customer2', 'product1', 1, 12),
('customer2', 'product1', 2, 3),

('customer2', 'product2', 3, 2),
('customer2', 'product2', 6, 5),
('customer2', 'product2', 8, 4),
('customer2', 'product2', 2, 11),
('customer2', 'product2', 1, 2)

select customer, product, sum(qty) as units, (sum(qty * price))/SUM(qty) as 'Average Price' from @table 
group by customer, product
```

Comment: Had a bug in the original code; this updated code calculates everything correctly.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.  I can't just average the prices.  I need to group based on the number of units sold in another table.  It also needs to accomodate date order.

Comment: Sorry man, you're hurting my brain. If I can muster the energy to try to parse this thing again, I'll give it another go. :-)